# Convert .sh file to a batch file for execution in windows

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

Can anyone help me convert the following shellscript code in a batch file?? i would be very helpful since i dont know the process. it uses a command "convert" of opencv 3.0 which i will modify after you have converted it. if anyone could modify the rest..thanks in advance for helping

```
for filename in $(ls *.pgm);
  do
    w=`convert $filename -print "%w" /dev/null`
    h=`convert $filename -print "%h" /dev/null`
    let "ww= $w/100"
    let "hh= $h/100"
    for((y=150;y<=250;y+=50))
      do
        for((i=100;i<=400;i+=50))
           do
             echo "slide/$i.$filename"
             let "h_slide=$i"
             convert $filename -crop 100x100+$i+$y slide/$y.$i.$filename
           done
      done
 done
```

Comment: @JamieSee  I saw your answer in the other post. Could you please help??

Comment: @voithos I saw your answer in the other post. Could you please help??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code writing service

Comment: you can only vote to close.. someone who want to help always helps..please feel free to close the question..i have got my answer that i needed. THANK YOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the `convert` commands are from `ImageMagick` not `OpenCV`.

Secondly, lines 3-6 can be removed since `w`,`ww`,`h` and `hh` are not used.

Thirdly, see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) for how to loop through files on Windows - to replace your current line 1.

Fourthly, see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) for how to loop through a range of numbers with a step of 50 - to replace your current line 7 and 9.

And a word of warning... Windows ships with a program called `CONVERT.EXE` that converts filesystems to NTFS, so if you want to run the `ImageMagick` `convert` rather than the Windows one, you better call it with something like `"C:\Programs\Installed\ImageMagick6-9.1\convert"` rather than plain `convert` else you'll get the wrong one.